# MVC ориентированная архитектура JSF

Tags: mvc, jsf, dao

Всем привет! В JSF фрейморке использую DAO для доступа к данным БД, согласно модели MVC к чему относится данный java-класс?

Comment: Считайте, что DAO относится к M из MVC.

Comment: Спасибо, но как аргументировать, что DAO относится именно к модели?

Comment: От противного. Предположить, что DAO - это V. Достаточно очевидно, что это нет так. Потом предположить, что DAO - это C. Опять не годится. C должен управлять среди прочего и V, чем DAO не занимает (не должен заниматься). Остаётся M, которая может быть всем, чем угодно:)